# Add columns to a dataframe based on entries from a character vector

Tags: r

I have a vector of character values which I wish to use in order to add columns to an existing dataframe, the columns named after the entries in the vector.

So if my vector were

```
vec
[1] "0.4" "0.5" "0.7"
```

And my dataframe were

```
df
          chars     nums
1           a       1
2           b       2
```

I would like to produce:

```
df
          chars     nums    0.4      0.5    0.7
1           a       1      "0.4"    "0.5"  "0.7"
2           b       2      "0.4"    "0.5"  "0.7"
```

Does anyone know how I might do this *without a for loop* ?

Comment: Please use proper terminology. `vec` is not a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
cbind(df,as.list(vec))
```

Or

```
df[vec] <- as.list(vec)
df
#  chars nums 0.4 0.5 0.7
#1     a    1 0.4 0.5 0.7
#2     b    2 0.4 0.5 0.7
```